# Managing Markers panel in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I've got an error showing in the Markers panel that doesn't actually affect anything. Is there a way to officially ignore it so I can stop looking at that red x?

FWIW, the error is an XML problem:

```
Referenced file contains errors (http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd).  For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..." 
applicationContext.xml  
/myproj/WebContent/WEB-INF  
line 1  
XML Problem
```

And when I say that it "doesn't actually affect anything" I mean that while it may have repercussions for prod, it doesn't seem to be affecting my dev environment & builds, which is all I care about at the moment....

Comment: What is the error? (What language?) Are you sure it really doesn't affect anything? IME the general rule is that if it's shown as an error, you can't safely ignore it.

Comment: edited the question to address your points.

Answer (score 1):

**Turn off the validation.**

Go to Window->Preferences->Validation and turn off the XML Schema Validator and the XML Validator.

If you only want to disable the validation for a single project, go to Project->Properties->Validation. Check the 'Enable project specific setting' box and then disable the XML/Schema validation.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of marker is it? Java problem? plug-in problem? some other? Mostly there will be some preference which if you change to 'Ignore', builder will not generate markers for that kind of problems.